# debian / screen freeze but system working

Tags: debian, x11, drivers, freeze, radeon

I've recently installed a dual-boot Debian Jessie / Win10 on a 64bit tower PC, and I'm having serious issues with Debian's install.
Out of the blue the screen/mouse/keyboard freeze, while the system still runs in the background. I'm therefore forced to issue a reboot command through SSH. Last time it happened I managed to dump dmesg output to file, and I'm pasting here what I believe is the juicy part:

```
[ 1202.602876] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=1c:af:f7:73:6f:de:a4:b1:e9:89:5a:58:08:00 SRC=172.217.21.46 DST=192.168.1.68 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=58255 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=58955 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
[ 1219.584178] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=1c:af:f7:73:6f:de:a4:b1:e9:89:5a:58:08:00 SRC=216.58.212.110 DST=192.168.1.68 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=35982 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=47141 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
[ 1515.744058] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000008
[ 1515.744123] IP: [<ffffffffa03c4c3d>] radeon_fence_ref+0xd/0x50 [radeon]
[ 1515.744204] PGD 0 
[ 1515.744219] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP 
[ 1515.744244] Modules linked in: ctr ccm ipheth binfmt_misc nfsd auth_rpcgss oid_registry nfs_acl nfs lockd fscache sunrpc ip6t_REJECT xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ipt_REJECT xt_LOG arc4 xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype rt2800usb rt2x00usb rt2800lib nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 rt2x00lib xt_conntrack mac80211 cfg80211 crc_ccitt rfkill ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables joydev snd_hda_codec_via snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep kvm_amd snd_pcm kvm snd_timer snd edac_mce_amd sp5100_tco shpchp soundcore edac_core pcspkr serio_raw i2c_piix4 k10temp tpm_infineon asus_atk0110 tpm_tis tpm evdev acpi_cpufreq
[ 1515.744766]  processor thermal_sys vmhgfs(O) vmw_vmci fuse parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 hid_generic usbhid hid sd_mod crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic sg sr_mod cdrom crct10dif_common ata_generic ohci_pci pata_atiixp radeon ohci_hcd ehci_pci ehci_hcd i2c_algo_bit ttm ahci drm_kms_helper libahci psmouse r8169 mii libata drm usbcore scsi_mod usb_common i2c_core wmi floppy button
[ 1515.745043] CPU: 3 PID: 737 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G           O  3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-1
[ 1515.745099] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/M3A78-CM, BIOS 0603    09/01/2008
[ 1515.745154] task: ffff8800c9bae2d0 ti: ffff8800ca26c000 task.ti: ffff8800ca26c000
[ 1515.745200] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa03c4c3d>]  [<ffffffffa03c4c3d>] radeon_fence_ref+0xd/0x50 [radeon]
[ 1515.745270] RSP: 0018:ffff8800ca26fb18  EFLAGS: 00010292
[ 1515.745302] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8800c3b3d5f8 RCX: ffff8800c3b3cd08
[ 1515.745345] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[ 1515.745388] RBP: ffff8800c3b3d550 R08: ffff8800c3b3c000 R09: 0000000000000000
[ 1515.745431] R10: 0000000000000002 R11: ffff8800ca26fe08 R12: 0000000000000020
[ 1515.745474] R13: ffff8800ca26fbe0 R14: ffff8800ca26fbb0 R15: ffff8800c3b3d5f8
[ 1515.745517] FS:  00007f5d94d81980(0000) GS:ffff88012fd80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 1515.745565] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 1515.745600] CR2: 0000000000000008 CR3: 000000012aba8000 CR4: 00000000000007e0
[ 1515.745643] Stack:
[ 1515.745656]  ffffffffa04250bc 00200000000730c0 0000f0a000000100 ffff8800ca26fcd0
[ 1515.745706]  ffff8800c3b3c000 ffff8800c9bae2d0 ffff8800c9bae2d0 0000000000000001
[ 1515.745756]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[ 1515.745805] Call Trace:
[ 1515.745842]  [<ffffffffa04250bc>] ? radeon_sa_bo_new+0x25c/0x460 [radeon]
[ 1515.745901]  [<ffffffffa03d9f3e>] ? radeon_ib_get+0x2e/0xd0 [radeon]
[ 1515.745955]  [<ffffffffa03dc47c>] ? radeon_cs_ioctl+0x13c/0x730 [radeon]
[ 1515.746008]  [<ffffffffa01088b7>] ? drm_ioctl+0x1c7/0x5b0 [drm]
[ 1515.746050]  [<ffffffff81057311>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1d1/0x4f0
[ 1515.746098]  [<ffffffffa03a9046>] ? radeon_drm_ioctl+0x46/0x80 [radeon]
[ 1515.746140]  [<ffffffff811bacdf>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x2cf/0x4b0
[ 1515.746176]  [<ffffffff811baf41>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x81/0xa0
[ 1515.746210]  [<ffffffff81514a0d>] ? system_call_fast_compare_end+0x10/0x15
[ 1515.746251] Code: e4 48 8b 3b 89 c1 89 ea 48 c7 c6 80 46 4b a0 31 c0 e8 68 c7 fd e0 eb cb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 66 66 66 66 90 48 89 f8 ba 01 00 00 00 <f0> 0f c1 57 08 83 c2 01 83 fa 01 7e 01 c3 80 3d 0e 43 11 00 00 
[ 1515.746457] RIP  [<ffffffffa03c4c3d>] radeon_fence_ref+0xd/0x50 [radeon]
[ 1515.746512]  RSP <ffff8800ca26fb18>
[ 1515.746533] CR2: 0000000000000008
[ 1515.761842] ---[ end trace 091f4dd21b1f5d9d ]---
[ 1549.661768] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=1c:af:f7:73:6f:de:a4:b1:e9:89:5a:58:08:00 SRC=172.217.21.46 DST=192.168.1.68 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=34587 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=58818 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
[ 1567.615309] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=1c:af:f7:73:6f:de:a4:b1:e9:89:5a:58:08:00 SRC=216.58.212.68 DST=192.168.1.68 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=2456 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=55948 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

I can only understand I'm having some sort of troubles with the ATI Radeon drivers. If I recall correcly, the video card drivers worked out of the box, and I sincerely have no idea if and how to eventually source bug-less drivers for it.

I've also been including two lines before and two after the crash, both showing (and there's a LOT more similar attempts in the log) some UFW blocked incoming connections, so I don't feel like ruling out the attack theory, but please prove me wrong on this theory.
In any case it seems impossible to recreate the issue..

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a kernel bug, please [report it](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianKernelReportingBugs), then try a newer *linux-image-amd64* package from the official [backports repository](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports). If that still exhibits the problem, try an upstream kernel as explained in [1](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianKernelReportingBugs).